# How does the AC bonus of a Monk's belt work when worn by a non-monk?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, monk, armor-class

The monk class states:

> AC Bonus (Ex): A monk is highly trained at dodging blows, and she has a sixth sense that lets her avoid even unanticipated attacks. When unarmored and unencumbered, the monk adds her Wisdom bonus (if any) to her AC. In addition, a monk gains a +1 bonus to AC at 5th level. This bonus increases by 1 for every five monk levels thereafter (+2 at 10th, +3 at 15th, and +4 at 20th level).
>   These bonuses to AC apply even against touch attacks or when the monk is flat-footed. She loses these bonuses when she is immobilized or helpless, when she wears any armor, when she carries a shield, or when she carries a medium or heavy load.

Now, the item Monk's Belt states:

> If the character is not a monk, she gains the AC and unarmed damage of a 5th-level monk. This AC bonus functions just like the monk’s AC bonus.

**My question:** If an unarmored druid wears a monk's belt, does he only get the +1 bonus to AC like a 5th level monk, or does he get both the +1 and his Wis modifier as a bonus to his AC?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Monk's Belt, as you quoted, says:

> If the character is not a monk, she **gains the AC** and unarmed damage **of a 5th-level monk**. This AC bonus functions **just like the monk’s AC bonus**.

So, what is the AC of a 5th level monk?

> When unarmored and unencumbered, **the monk adds her Wisdom bonus (if any) to her AC. In addition, a monk gains a +1 bonus to AC at 5th level.**

*All* of that is "the AC... of a 5th-level monk". Since it functions just like the monk's AC bonus, you will also lose it if you are armored or encumbered.